# Error in Python: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to make a list out of data from an excel file in python, but I receive this whenever I run my code

```
row[1] = int(row[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

This is the code I have that sorts it (by minimum, maximum, and average)

```
f = open("Class 2.csv", "r")
csvread = csv.reader(f)
nlist = []
for row in csvread:
    filter(lambda x: 3 > 0, row)
    row[0] = int(row[0])
    row[1] = int(row[1])
    row[2] = int(row[2])
    row[3] = int(row[3])
    minimum = min(row[1:4])
    row.append(minimum)
    maximum = max(row[1:4])
    row.append(maximum)
    average = round(sum(row[1:4])/3)
    row.append(average)
    nlist.append(row[0:4])
print(nlist)
```

Row[0] in my excel file is a name as well, so I also get an error that tells me that int(row[0]) cannot work because I is not an integer. I don't know how to change it so that I don't get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Iteration *row* has no second element. Check it before sending:

If all values in list are numbers, use **map** for str to int values:

```
int_values = map(int, str_list)
```

or

```
int_values = map(int, str_list[0:4])
```

But this will not solve your problem, because in the list of values.

Comment: I hope this isn't a silly comment, but what do you mean by "second element"?

Comment: Your first example. row[1] - it's secont element.